# Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to Y-m-d in PHP

Tags: php

I am using below code for converting whole data in Y-m-d format in PHP

```
<?php 
$from_date ="Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
$from_date = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $from_date)); // Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530
$from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date)); //actual output-2020-10-31 expected output-2020-11-01  
?>
```

I want date as 2020-11-01 but its returning 2020-10-31

Comment: Probably means your default timezone is set to UTC, which would be +0, so is giving the right result. You can change the default timezone, but it depends what you actually need.

Comment: how can I change my current timezone.. can you rewrite my code to give proper output?

Comment: Check out [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: I am simply converting Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to Y-m-d format. how timezone will affect

Comment: If you convert that to GMT+0530 to GMT+0, then you're effectively removing 5 hours and 30 mins, which would make it the day before if you're counting from midnight.

Comment: please give the solution of this. I am new to PHP, so if someone rewrite my code then it will best to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224716/discussion-between-imnik18-and-jonnix).

Comment: Easy way, use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) instead. Rather than using `$from_date = date('Y-m-d'....)`, try using `$fromDt = new DateTime($from_date); echo $fromDt->format('Y-m-d');` which will take into account the timezone.

Comment: can you edit my code with this solution

Comment: No. Please at least do that much yourself, it's a copy and paste job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a time zone in the date string, this must also be taken into account. The DateTime class offers methods for this. Removing the brackets and their content is ok, "GMT +0530" is sufficient for the time zone.

```
$from_date ="Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
$from_date = trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $from_date)); // Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s O',$from_date);

//test output
var_dump($dt);
//object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-11-01 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+05:30" }

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
// 2020-11-01
```

This code works independently of the time zone set on the server.